# Regex: Capture a group of lines with the same beginnings?

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a script to go through a product database with poorly, inconsistently formatted product descriptions to make its HTML uniform. One problem I'm having is capturing and replacing lines of code formatted the same way. For example, I'd like to replace all their

```
&bull; item 1
&bull; item 2
&bull; item 3
```

with

```
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Replacing each `&bull;` line with a `<li>content</li>` line is easy enough, but I can't for the life of me figure out the regex to get before and after the list. My though is to capture everything starting with `&bull;` until there is a newline that does **not** start with `&bull;`. Here's my latest try (python):

```
In  : p = re.compile(
        r'&bull;.*(?!^&bull;)'
      )

In  : p.findall(text, re.MULTILINE, re.DOTALL)
Out : []

In  : p.findall(text, re.MULTILINE)
Out : ['&bull; item 1', '&bull; item 2', '&bull; item 3']

In  : p.findall(text, re.DOTALL)
Out : ['&bull; item 1', '&bull; item 2', '&bull; item 3']

In  : p.findall(text)
Out : ['&bull; item 1', '&bull; item 2', '&bull; item 3']
```

Any ideas on how to capture something like `['&bull; item 1\n&bull; item 2\n&bull; item 3']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a non-regex based solution:

```
with open('/tmp/example.txt') as f:
  lines_in = f.readlines()

inside_block = False
lines_out = []

for line in lines_in:
  if line.startswith('&bull; '):
    if not inside_block:
      lines_out.append('<ul>\n')
      inside_block = True
    lines_out.append('<li>{}</li>\n'.format(line.strip().replace('&bull; ','')))
  else:
    if inside_block:
      lines_out.append('</ul>\n')
      inside_block = False
    lines_out.append(line)

print ''.join(lines_in)
print '-'*78
print ''.join(lines_out)
```

Test run:

```
[~/Desktop]
|7>run /tmp/spam.py
spam
&bull; item 1
&bull; item 2
&bull; item 3
and eggs

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
spam
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
<li>item 3</li>
</ul>
and eggs
```

Comment: Thanks friend! Python's re module wasn't matching how it should have been, at least not according to other answers in this thread and [regexpal](http://www.regexpal.com). This is pretty elegant IMO. Also, I needed to match `&bull;` occurrences _before_ changing to `<li>` elements (or do it at the same time), because the database already has both types of lists and I didn't want to break the existing `<ul>`s, which your method accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

You will first have to change all the bullets to `<li>` elements, then on a second execution encompass them in `<ul>` element.

Here is a java example. Python also uses PCRE so it should work the same:

```
    String test = "&bull; item 1\r\n&bull; item 2\r\n&bull; item 3\r\n";
    test = test.replaceAll("&bull; (.*)(?!^&bull;)", "<li>$1</li>");
    System.out.println(test);
    test = test.replaceAll("(?s)(<li>.+</li>)+?", "<ul>\n$1\n</ul>");
    System.out.println(test);
```

Output:

```
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
<li>item 3</li>

<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
<li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This should have worked, as it does in JS and [regexpal](http://regexpal.com), but Python's regex module is finicky.

Answer (score 0):

Read the contents into a string and split on "&bull;". Iterate over the elements adding "<li>" and "<\li>" before and after each element, respectively.

Comment: Hope you don't mind that I put backticks around parts of the answer that would otherwise be interpreted as HTML.